# Reorder Columns for Mobile Foundation 5

Tags: jquery, css, zurb-foundation

I am working on my portfolio site and on my project pages, I am using Foundation 5's rows and columns to display a large image and a caption box. For the projects with more than one image and caption, I am alternating the layout.

Here is the desktop layout: 
[Caption][Large Image] 
[Large Image][Caption] 
[Caption][Large Image]

The mobile layout is rendering like this (which makes sense): 
[Caption]
[Large Image] 
[Large Image]
[Caption] 
[Caption]
[Large Image]

I really want the images to display above the captions once the screen size goes below 1025px. I have tried applying new floats to the columns and I have tried Foundation's push/pull classes, but nothing has worked. I think that the solution will most likely require jQuery, but I have been unable to get the floats to override Foundation's layout.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="caption small-11 medium-8 large-4 small-centered medium-centered large-uncentered c   olumn">Caption</div>
<div class="large_image medium-10 large-8 medium-centered large-uncentered column">Large Image</div>    
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="large_image medium-10 large-8 medium-centered large-uncentered column">Large Image</div>
<div class="caption small-11 medium-8 large-4 small-centered medium-centered large-uncentered c   olumn">Caption</div>    
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="caption small-11 medium-8 large-4 small-centered medium-centered large-uncentered c   olumn">Caption</div>
<div class="large_image medium-10 large-8 medium-centered large-uncentered column">Large Image</div>    
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You may use mediaqueries and display:flex; or pseudo-element and float and clear methods.

display:flex + mediaqueries http://codepen.io/anon/pen/unfgB

```
body {
  margin:0;
}
.row {
  overflow:hidden;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
}
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;/*to show borders */
}
.caption,
.large_image {
  border:solid;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.caption {
  width:30%;
}
.large_image {
  width:70%;
  min-width:500px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 714px) { /* based on large_image at min-width 500px and caption at 30% width */
  .row{
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .caption {
    order:1;
  }
  .large_image {
    order:2;
  }


}
```

**Or float and pseudo methods**
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lEdmH

```
body {
  margin:0;
}
.row {
  overflow:hidden;
  width:100%;
}
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;/*to show borders */
}
.caption,
.large_image {
  border:solid;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.caption {
  width:30%;
}
.large_image {
  width:70%;
  min-width:500px;
}
.row :nth-child(1) {
  float:left;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 714px) { /* based on large_image at min-width 500px and caption at 30% width */
  .large_image {
    clear:left;
  }

.row:before {
  content:'';
  float:left;
  height:1.6em;/* this should be height of caption */
}
}
```

margins, box-sizing and width are for test purpose.

in both cases , mediaquerie is used, but in javascript or Jquery you can check it out and apply an extra class to .row and keep one or the other CSS used in those 2 test.

Comment: Thanks I am going to give this a try.  I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using presentational classes you should try to use the push / pull classes. It is counter intuitive but I will attempt to explain it.

You should place your columns in the order that you would like them to appear in Mobile / Small. Also, the medium grid inherits its size from the small / mobile grid, however, it inherits the push / pull classes from the large grid.

With those two things in mind, you can modify your to something like so:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large_image medium-8 large-8 push-4 column"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/300x300" alt=""></div>    
  <div class="caption medium-4 large-4 pull-8 column">Caption</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="large_image medium-8 large-8 column"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/300x300" alt=""></div>
  <div class="caption medium-4 large-4 column">Caption</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="large_image medium-8 large-8 push-4 column"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/300x300" alt=""></div>    
  <div class="caption medium-4 large-4 pull-8 column">Caption</div>
</div>
```

I am showing this with out the small-11 small-centered medium-uncentered large-uncentered treatment just to more clearly demonstrate how the push / pull classes work.

Hope that helps.

If you are stuck with the idea of having the medium grid more closely resemble the mobile grid you can change the default media query ranges to effectively make the mobile grid also encompass the tablet range or you will have to write custom CSS/Scss Media Queries such as in the previous answer.